# Show that $\angle$AXC = $\angle$ACB

Tags: geometry, circles, triangles, geometric-construction, angle

[image]

The image shows an acute angled triangle of 30 degrees with sides of 8cm & 5 cm.

A perpendicular has been constructed from point A to the side BC. & the point it meets side BC is marked D.

A circle is drawn through the points A ,D & C.

A tangent is constructed to the circle from point C.

The side it meets AD produced is marked X

Show that $\angle$AXC = $\angle$ACB , Any Ideas on how to begin ?

Comment: Both angles are the complementary angle of $\widehat{BCX}=\widehat{CBA}=30^\circ$, for instance.

Comment: A little tough to read.  But is it given that $\angle ACX, \angle CAB, \angle XDC$ are all right angles?

Comment: @Doug M yes I guess they all are right angles

Comment: $\angle$CAB is not necessarily a right angle.

Comment: Here is a more precise version of the diagram, constructed using Geogebra: http://i.stack.imgur.com/su47Q.png.

Comment: @Semiclassical Thank you

Answer (score 4):

$\triangle ACX$ is a right triangle with altitude $D.$

$\triangle XDC \sim \triangle CDA ~\sim \triangle XCA$

And that is all you need.

Comment: Just a note to anyone (like me) that was confused why $A$, $C$ and the centre of circle $ADC$ are collinear: since $ADC$ is a right angle, $AC$ must be a diameter of circle $ADC$ since the angle subtended by a diameter is a right angle.